# Strange behaviour of Ant java webapplication in Netbeans 10 and later

Tags: java, class, tomcat, netbeans

I have a Wicket java webapplication Ant project created in Netbeans 7.3. In the past the project has moved to Netbeans 8.2 and 9.0. I use currently the OpenJDK11. I can still build, run and debug the project in Netbeans 9. But in Netbeans 10 and later (11.3), suddenly the project won't run in Tomcat 9. I have searched for the cause and found out that the class files are changed or deleted on the first attempt to run or debug after a **clean and build**. All the innerclasses and anonymous classes (*$.class) files in the projects **build directory** are deleted. Also the normal other class files were shrunked in size. After a **clean and build** command there is also a **war** file created in the **dist** directory. When I restore the class files in the **war** file to the **build** directory suddenly the project will run. I am looking for a solution for this strange behaviour. In Netbeans 9 everything works normally with the same project and Ant file. Also the Tomcat installation and JDK is the same. So I suspect Netbeans.

Comment: I fiddled something around in the Ant projectfile _build-impl.xml_ in the **DEBUG SECTION** and removed the option _-init-cos_ from the attribute _depends_ in the tag _target_. Now Netbeans starts debugging without error. But now deploy on save will not work anymore, I think. This is the _-init-cos_ definition in _build-impl.xml_:
<target depends="init" name="-init-cos" unless="deploy.on.save">
<condition property="deploy.on.save" value="true">
<or>
      <istrue value="${j2ee.deploy.on.save}"/>
      <istrue value="${j2ee.compile.on.save}"/>
</or>
</condition>
</target>

Comment: I can definitive confirm that the problem is related to the settings of _Project->Build->Compiling->Compile-on-Save_ and _Project->Run->Deploy-on-Save_ settings. With both settings switched off (and the unaltered build-impl.xml), the problem doesn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is caused by a missing plugin *The nb-javac Java Editing support library version 2.0* from the source *Third Party Libraries*. This is a modified/patched javac to integrate well to facilitate *Compile on Save* and *Deply on Save*. More information about (the old version of) this plugin can be found here: [What's "nb-javac" in Apache NetBeans?](https://blogs.apache.org/netbeans/entry/what-s-nb-javac-in).
You can install the plugin via MainMenu=>Tools=>Plugins